# Is it truck factor or bus factor?

Tags: agile

It seems that both these terms get thrown around a lot.  Both, I think, describe the same idea.  Which was established first?

Also, it seems like some people describe it as a good thing to have a low x factor, while others describe it as a good thing to have a high x factor.  Which is it?

Comment: What is truck/bus factor? What is this same idea in which original description?

Comment: All, good info on the high/low comparison.  I still think no one has claimed to know what the name of the term was when it was first established.  Also, the point has been made that it doesn't really matter as long as you observe the idea.  Still, I'm curious.

Comment: As a civil engineer that does a lot of programming in the freight (trucking) industry, the question title confused the hell out of me

Comment: It might as well be called the car factor, according to the folklore. http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=I_Still_Remember_Regions.txt  (btw, I heard this story when I was an Apple Engineer in the early 90s)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia says bus number is "[more commonly known as truck number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_bus_number)" But in the US, "hit by a bus" is practically an idiom, while "hit by a truck" is not (although either phrase is easily understood.) Regarding high/low being good, the wikipedia article says:

> "*High bus numbers are good* (with the
>   best case being equal to the number of
>   developers on a project). This means
>   all developers understand the codebase
>   more or less equally. A low bus number
>   (especially, one) represents a high
>   risk."

I'd add to what [@cartoonfox said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164692/is-it-truck-factor-or-bus-factor/2165539#2165539): ***Promiscuous* pair progamming is a good way to distribute critical knowledge around a team so that the truck number is as high as possible.** If you don't swap pairs *often* and with many different team members, knowledge isn't distributed very quickly.

Comment: I've come to prefer "lottery number" over "vehicle number", to leave the gruesome death aspect out.

Answer (score 13):

You want a high truck/bus factor:

> Truck Factor (definition): "The number
>   of people on your team who have to be
>   hit with a truck before the project is
>   in serious trouble"

(From: http://www.agileadvice.com/archives/2005/05/truck_factor.html)

i.e. you don't want parts of the code that only one person knows how it works or only one person can extend/maintain.  Knowledge should be spread amongst the whole team via things like wiki info and pair-programming.

Comment: The corollary is that a higher truck factor leads to employees that feel more expendable and replaceable - after all, the project will probably go on even if they're creamed by a truck.

Comment: In some parts of America, it's a "Bus Factor" because we worry more about being hit by a bus than by a truck. No good reason for that.  Any more than there's a good reason for Apple Pie being the "America" dish.  But "Bus Factor" would be slightly more common to Americans than "Truck" factor.

Comment: @S.Lott -- haha, I love the reasoning. :)

Comment: Well, I have yet to hear of a "Lorry Factor".

Comment: I thought McDonald's was the American dish!

Comment: @trinithis: From outside it may look that way.  And all the objective evidence may point that way.  But the phrase is "Mom and Apple Pie".

Comment: here, it seems to be a higher probability of being hit by a taxi/cab...

Answer (score 3):

The **Truck Number** (or Truck Factor) is the number of people with key knowledge that you cannot replace i.e. if that number of people went simultaneously under a truck you wouldn't be able to carry on developing.

I believe that certain chemical companies forbid key members of staff from travelling together for this very reason...

**Discussion here:** http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TruckNumber

**Here's a story about Bill Atkinson being the one key person in the Mac's truck factor** - one of the key people that worked on QuickDraw during the early days of the Mac. Had a car accident apparently and people were concerned that he wouldn't be able to finish his work on the Mac's graphics software:

http://folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=I_Still_Remember_Regions.txt

**A high truck number is better** - i.e. it's harder to wipe out that many critical people at once...

**A low truck number is worse** - i.e. there is a greater risk that a few critical people could be ill, or leave or die, leaving the project in a state of unrecoverable collapse.

**Pair progamming is a good way to distribute critical knowledge around a team** so that the truck number is as high as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The principle is the same, whether you call it:

- bus number
- truck number
- bus factor
- truck factor
- et al

Also, the principle is the same whether or not you describe it using a higher number as being better, or a lower number being better:

- A high bus number is good if you are describing the number of project members who could be hit by a bus and have the project survive;
- A low bus number is good if you are describing the number of project members who survive a bus crash and have the project survive.

I did look into it once upon a time, but I don't recall which came first (see @Paolo's answer).  Regardless of which came first, I have experienced enough confusion about it that I make sure all parties are using the same version of the number, high or low.  ;)